# MASM 32-bit 2d arrays accessing with conditional control flow directives error A2029:multiple base registers not allowed

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

```
updateBoard PROC array:PTR DWORD , row1: DWORD, col1:DWORD, row2:DWORD , col2:DWORD
    LOCAL isSame:DWORD, exitLoop: DWORD, value1:DWORD

    mov isSame, 0 ;isSame = false
    mov exitLoop, 0


    ;computing smaller column, we'll start from the column which has smaller position for rowwise forward computation
    mov eax, col2
    .if( col1 < eax )
        mov ecx, col1
    .elseif 
        mov ecx, col2
    .endif


    ;rowWise forward combos

        mov eax, ecx; starting column index 
        mov edi,row1 ; row index
        mov esi, eax
        mov edx, 10
        sub edx, ecx; computing loop counter -> (10 - col index with greater value  )
        .while ( edx < 9d AND exitLoop == 0)

                mov ecx, array[edi + eax*TYPE array]
                
                add eax, 1d
                mov ebx, array[edi + eax*TYPE array]

                .if ( ecx == ebx )
                    mov isSame, 1 ; isSame = true
                .endif
                
                .if ( ecx != ebx )
                    mov exitLoop, 1
                .endif

            inc esi
            mov eax, esi
            inc edx
        .endw

        
        dec eax
        displayString offset prompt7
        call writeDec

    ret
updateBoard ENDP
```

also got this error after including `..AND exitLoop ==0`A2154 syntax error in control-flow directive
i'm making a 2d board game- Number Crush. i was checking for forward row-wise matches first and been getting this error no matter what i try. i was using both edi and esi for the array accessing but changed it esi to eax.  Please help.
I've look up the internet which says that it's a fatal error.

Comment: Is `AND` a valid keyword? Try `&&` instead.

Comment: thanks Jester. How do I remove the one that says 'multiple use of base register'. I know that base registers are edi, esi, ebx, and ebp. I tried modifying the instructions but it still doesn't  go away. I am a beginner so I'm sorry if I'm making some beginner mistakes here.

Comment: If i change the ```array```  with ```board1``` , which is the name of the board i declared in  ```.data``` , i get no error. Can someone explain to me why this happend? This is how i called this procedure ```INVOKE updateBoard ,ADDR  board1, row1, col1, row2, col2```.

Comment: You need to show a minimal, complete example that reproduces the problem you describe.